# 13 Hearts but Nothing else

Tags: riddle

What has 13 hearts, but no other organs?
There is a very simple answer which you will be kicking yourself over after you see it.
There is only one possible answer...

Comment: Someone told me this riddle two weeks ago (to which I guessed the answer correctly). But the point is, that means you might have not come up with the riddle yourself. If that is the case, please include where or how you found the riddle.

Comment: Since @user477343's answer was considered the correct one (at least among some religious community), and since F1Krazy's answer seems definitely valid, there is apparently not "one possible answer".

Comment: A third possible answer is "this shirt I'm currently wearing" ;)

Comment: @jafe Hahahah :D

Comment: Another alternative answer:  My freezer. Please don't call the cops.

Answer (score 6):

This is

> a deck of playing cards.

Explanation:

> There are 13 Hearts cards in a standard deck: King, Queen, Jack, Ace, and 2-10.

Answer (score 4):

You might have said there can only be one answer... but the answer could also be, from a religious perspective,

> **1 Corinthians 13** in the New Testament of the Christian Bible.

`What has 13 hearts, but no other organs?`

> 1 Corinthians 13 was written by [St. Paul](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL58g24NgWPIzvBk2IQVES_xC4WTm6-CDI&time_continue=34&v=LQoxL1AJYdw) for which it has 13 verses, each talking about **love**. Of course, a **heart** resembles love. If you wish to read it, you can over [here](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+13&version=NIV).

Answer (score 1):

It is:

> A deck of cards.

Reason:

> A deck of cards contain 52 cards out of which 13 cards are of the heart suite.

Comment: Look at [@F1Krazy's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68947/13-hearts-but-nothing-else/68949#68949).

Comment: No problem. Somebody down-voted this answer, but they have to take into consideration that you are new to this site, wherefore I strongly suggest you visit the [**Help Center**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help). You can get all the information there, but the sections explaining asking and answering are most important, so check them out. I hope you enjoy this site, and that you make good contributions to this community in the future :D